# My python installer freezes while working. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I made a very simple GUI Installer for a game with wxPython. Although it is meant for a game it can technically be used to download and extract any zip file if you have the link. The problem is when I run the program the GUI freezes. It still downloads and extracts like its supposed to, but the GUI is completely frozen while this happens. I can't update text boxes or make a download bar unless I can unfreeze it.  I know why it freezes I just don't know how to fix it. Could someone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
import requests, os, sys, zipfile, shutil, subprocess, wx, urllib

url = "{Put any zip file URL here to test the program}"
r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        myButton = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, 'Download', size=(300,50), pos=(40,350))
        myButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
        self.Show(True)
    def onClick(self, e):
        print ('Clicked')
        if os.path.exists("RFMB6_WINDOWS"):
            print('\n\nRemoving old RFMP files...')
            subprocess.check_call(('attrib -R ' + 'RFMB6_WINDOWS' + '\\* /S').split())
            shutil.rmtree('RFMB6_WINDOWS')
            print('\nRemoved old files.')
        else:
            pass

        print('\n\nDownloading:')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'RFMP.zip')
        print('\nDownload Complete.')
        print('\n\nExtracting...')
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("RFMP.zip", 'r')
        zip_ref.extractall("RFMB6_WINDOWS")
        zip_ref.close()
        print('\nExtraction Complete')
        print('\n\nCleaning up...')
        os.remove("RFMP.zip")
        print('\nDone! You have succesfully installed the newest version of the Ravenfield Multiplayer Private Alpha.')

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Image')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How long does it take you to download the zip file? It could be freezing because it's still downloading the file. What happens if you let it run?

Comment: The program works fine, but it freezes and says 'not responding' while downloading. I need some way to multi thread it I just don't know how. Like I said, I know why its freezing, I just need to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. As I said I needed to multi-thread the GUI, but at the time I couldn't figure it out. Now I have. What I needed to do was multi-thread the GUI and my 'processes' on separate threads. This means that the GUI (what you see) is running on a separate thread than the one that is processing the data (downloading, extracting, etc.).

Before you use this code I want to let you know this is not a finished program. It is just the bare minimum to download and extract a .zip from a download link without freezing.

Here is the code I am using now to solve my problem:

```
# Import libraries
import requests, os, sys, zipfile, shutil, subprocess, wx, urllib, time
from threading import *

# Define variables
url = "Put any zip file URL here to test the program"
r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

# Button definitions
ID_START = wx.NewId()

# Define notification event for thread completion
EVT_RESULT_ID = wx.NewId()

# Check  for old files
def Check():
    if os.path.exists("Folder"):
        print('\n\nRemoving old files...')
        subprocess.check_call(('attrib -R ' + 'Folder' + '\\* /S').split())
        shutil.rmtree('Folder')
        print('\nRemoved old files.')
    else:
        pass

# Download new file
def Download():
    print('\n\nDownloading:')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'temp.zip')
    print('\nDownload Complete.')

# Extract new file
def Extract():
    print('\n\nExtracting...')
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("temp.zip", 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall("Folder")
    zip_ref.close()
    print('\nExtraction Complete')

# Delete the .zip file but leave the folder
def Clean():
    print('\n\nCleaning up...')
    os.remove("temp.zip")
    print('\nDone!')

# Thread class that executes processing
class WorkerThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        # This starts the thread running on creation.
        self.start()

# This is what runs on a separate thread when you click the download button
    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread. 
        Check()
        Download()
        Extract()
        Clean()

# GUI Frame class that spins off the worker thread
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Class MainFrame."""
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        """Create the MainFrame."""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'GUInstaller', 
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.SetSize(400, 350)
        wx.Button(self, ID_START, 'Download', size=(300,50), pos=(42,250))
        self.status = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '', pos=(0,200))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, id=ID_START)

        # And indicate we don't have a worker thread yet
        self.worker = None

    def OnStart(self, event):
        """Start Computation."""
        # Trigger the worker thread unless it's already busy
        if not self.worker:
            self.status.SetLabel('Downloading...')
            self.worker = WorkerThread(self)

    def OnResult(self, event):
        """Show Result status."""
        self.status.SetLabel('Done!')
        # The worker is done
        self.worker = None

class MainApp(wx.App):
    """Class Main App."""
    def OnInit(self):
        """Init Main App."""
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, -1)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

# Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

P.S. Not all of this is my code. I took an example from another website and modified it to work with my needs.